# Getting value of parent model with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, inheritance, backbone.js, mv

I have a backbone application with the following architecture:

A `PageGroupCollection` is a collection of `PageGroupModel`s.

A `PageGroupModel` has a `PageCollection` as one of it's attributes.

A `PageCollection` is a collection of `PageModel`s

---

`PageGroupModel` has a `permalink` attribute

`PageModel` has a `permalink` attribute.

I need a function within `PageModel` that returns a `permalink` that includes both the `permalink` of `PageModel` thats `PageCollection` attribute contains `PageGroupModel` and also its own `permalink` attribute.

Something like the following:

```
getFullPermalink: function () {

    var parentPermanlink = this.owningCollection.modelCollectionIsAnAttributeOf.get('permalink');

    return parentPermalink + "/" + this.get('permalink');
}
```

Update: Worked by adding the following:

```
var pageGroup = pageGroupCollection.findWhere({ 'pageCollection': this.collection });
var pageGroupPermalink = pageGroup.get('permalink');
return pageGroupPermalink + "/" + this.get('permalink');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone isn't really made to work with nested models (Backbone-Relational may be interesting). But if you have access to the entry point of your tree (in your example, to the instance of `PageGroupCollection`), you can do that:

```
var parent = myPageGroupCollection.findWhere({pageCollection: myPageModel.collection});
```

With `myPageModel` being your child model and `pageCollection` the collection attribute of the `PageGroupModel`.

Supposing you also don't mess with the `collection` attribute of your models (if your model is in several collections for example).