# How to treat nested collection events in Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

I have an API resource that gives me a list of `users` that each have several `items`.  The hierarchy is like so:

```
- users
  - user
    - items
      - item
      - item
      - item
  - user
    - items
      - item
      - item
      - item
```

I would like to display the list of `users` on a single page, with each `user` entry displaying each of its `items` on the page as well.

When any one of these `items` is clicked, it should set an `chosen` attribute that is accessible through the overall `users` collection.

I'm having difficulty getting the `item` click information to bubble back up.  My current implementation is creating a separate `items` collection in order to render the view, but then I lose the connection to its original `user` model, so I can't notify it when the `item` is selected.

My views are structured like so:

```
class List.Item extends Marionette.ItemView
  template: "path/to/template"

  events:
    "click" : "choose"

  choose: (e) ->
    # what to do?

class List.User extends Marionette.CompositeView
  collection: @collection
  template: "path/to/template"
  itemView: List.Item
  itemViewContainer: "span"

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Entities.Items(@model.get("items"), parent: @)

  events:
    "click a" : "toggleChoose"

  @include "Chooseable"

class List.Users extends Marionette.CollectionView
  itemView: List.User
```

Is there a better way to structure these collections or views, or is there a way to pass the information from the `List.Item` view to the parent `List.User` view and then into the `users` collection?

**EDIT**

I have tried backbone-relational, but it didn't seem to quite do what I need. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to instantiate the `items` collection to reference the parent `user` and vice-versa directly in Backbone:

```
class Entities.User extends Backbone.Model
  ...
  initialize: ->
    @items = new Entities.Items @get("items"),
      user: @

class Entities.Items extends Backbone.Collection
  ...
  initialize: (models, options) ->
    @user = options?.user
```

So now the `List.User` CompositeView can pass this information to the `List.Item` ItemView:

```
class List.User extends Marionette.CompositeView
  collection: @collection
  ...
  initialize: ->
    @collection = @model.items
```

With this in place, it is possible to access the `user` directly from the ItemView:

```
class List.Item extends Marionette.ItemView
  ...
  events:
    "click" : "choose"

  choose: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    user = @model.collection.user
    console.log "user: ", user
```

And from there it's possible to take any necessary actions on the `user` and its collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your List.Item should contain it's current model with all properties at the time when choose is triggered.  In this way, you can trigger other events with the List.Item's model values:

```
choose(e) : ->
  trigger("mylistitem:choose", model)
```

Then listen for the event elsewhere :

```
itemView.on("itemview:mylistitem:choose", ( childView, model ) -> {
 alert(model.get('..whatever..')
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the Item model doesn't hold any reference to its original user, so how would it be possible to set attributes on the user or users collection?

Comment: Looks like you will just need to instantiate your item model with a userId of some sort ( simplest solution ).  Otherwise, have a look at traversing a parent collection : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381113/getting-value-of-parent-model-with-backbone-js)here

Comment: How do you instantiate the Item model with an ID?  That would be the most natural solution to me, but I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: add an event handler to the add function of the collection - so whenever a child item is added to a collection you can set a model property.  [backbone.add](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add)